# Is the word subprocedure; sub-procedure; or sub procedure correct?

Tags: hyphenation, prefixes

I want to use the single word variety, but my spellchecker is telling me the split two words is correct. This looks wrong to me, is there a standard for this type of word and "prefix"?

Comment: Related and duplicate questions: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/889), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7657), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/60404), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/91203), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/110086), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/116878), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/129042), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/142700), [9](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/365159), [10](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/383553).

Comment: Don’t trust software: it makes up rubbish at the drop of a hat. Were you to write it as two separate words, it would be considered “wrong” because the standalone word *sub* is no  longer a prefix—usually a shortening of long words like *submarine* or *substitution*. Ad-hoc de-novo creations are usually hyphenated at first, but unless they’re prefixing a word that’s normally capitalized like *sub-Saharan*, tend to lose that hyphen if and when that word gains greater currency. The UK tends to keep these a bit longer than North America. Some publishing houses have specific policies about them.